# How to fix buffer error in using discord API

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fetch, buffer

I am going to give a role to discord users that hold some NFTs.
But I got some errors so I am struggle with it now.
Please help me.

```
import { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, GuildMember, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
  });
```

This is error image

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the full error message as text, and don't use pictures for this. What's your discord.js version? What's your node.js version?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Discord version is 13 and node is 16.